# Runtime error in cordova based Barcode Scanner hybrid app developed worklight 6.1

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, barcode-scanner

I was following a tutorial at this link

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/WASFAQs/entry/using_a_barcode_scanner_with_worklight?lang=en

through which i could develop a barcode scanner using worklight 6.1. But after following the tutorial step by step I am getting the following error in logcat ..

```
**02-25 04:33:05.013: D/AndroidRuntime(811): Shutting down VM
02-25 04:33:05.013: W/dalvikvm(811): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp/com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp.BarcodeScannerSampleApp}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp.BarcodeScannerSampleApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp-2, /system/lib]]
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp.BarcodeScannerSampleApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp-2, /system/lib]]
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
02-25 04:33:05.023: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  ... 11 more**
```

The AndroidManifest.xml is as follows:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>  
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>  
<!-- Push permissions -->  
<permission android:name="com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 


<!-- Adding camera permission here -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<!-- abcdefgh -->

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon"> 
    <activity android:name=".BarcodeScannerSampleApp" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp.BarcodeScannerSampleApp.NOTIFICATION"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>  
     <!-- ADDING CARdova support files here -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" android:label="@string/share_name">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
    <!-- abcdefgh -->
    <!-- Preference Activity  -->  
    <activity android:name="com.worklight.common.WLPreferences" android:label="Worklight Settings"></activity>  
    <!-- Push service  -->  
    <!-- In order to use the c2dm library, an application must declare a class with the name C2DMReceiver, in its own package, extending com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver 
        It must also include this section in the manifest, replacing "com.google.android.apps.chrometophone" with its package name. -->  
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>  
    <service android:name=".ForegroundService"/>  
    <!-- Only google service can send data messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->  
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> 
        <!-- Receive the actual message -->  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>  
            <category android:name="com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <!-- Receive the registration id -->  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>  
            <category android:name="com.BarcodeScannerSampleApp"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver> 





</application>
```

I added the following snippet to the config.xml file

```
<feature name="BarcodeScanner">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner"/>
</feature>
```

The index.html file present in app/BarcodeScannerSampleApp/common/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>index</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body >

            <!--application UI goes here-->
            <h1>Barcode scanner</h1>
            <button type="button" id="scanButton">Scan</button>

        <script>
        $('#scanButton').bind('click', doScan);

        function doScan()
            {
                cordova.exec(onScanSuccess, onScanFailure, 'BarcodeScanner', 'scan', []);
            }

        function onScanSuccess(result)
         {
            alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
         }

        function onScanFailure(error)
         {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
         }
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about config.xml? The JS? Where did you place the Java file?

Comment: js is added inline in the index.html file and the java files are in project/android/native/src/com/BarcodeScannerSampleApp,project/android/native/src/com/google , project/android/native/src/com/phonegap

Comment: Can you provide the Worklight project? Export it from Eclipse and upload to Dropbox or alike.

Answer (score 0):

this seems odd, because it is the default Java class for the Worklight application that is not found, not the Barcode scanner itself.  Does a simple application with Android target environment start up correctly?

The other thing you have not mentioned here is setting up the barcode scanner library project.  This is different from the Java added to your Worklight project.  Did you set this up too?  (although you'd get a different class not found for that) I actually had an issue where my Worklight project wasn't picking up the library.  I think I had an issue with the ADT tools where I couldn't set up the library reference correctly (it kept forgetting the setting).  I recreated the projects in a new Eclipse workspace and suddenly the library was resolved correctly.